# Yahoo New Weather API oAuth call in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, oauth

As of the 3rd of January Yahoo Weather has a new weather API that requires oAuth https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

Now I have gotten my Client ID (Consumer Key) and my Client Secret (Consumer Secret) from yahoo. My question is how would I call this API with oAuth in jquery or javascript?

Here is what a call looks like:

```
GET /forecastrss?location=sunnyvale,ca HTTP/1.1
Host: weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com
Yahoo-App-Id: YOUR_APP_ID
Authorization: OAuth
oauth_consumer_key="YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="YOUR_TIMESTAMP",oauth_nonce="YOUR_NONCE",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="YOUR_GENERATED_SIGNATURE"
cache-control: no-cache
```

and it states "Please also include your OAuth app id in the header."

What would this look like in jquery?

I have tried the following:

```
$.get("https://weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com/forecastrss", { location: "sunnyvale,ca", format: "json", oauth_consumer_key: "Client ID (Consumer Key)", oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1" } ).done(function( data ) {
        console.log("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
```

and I get this error:

> ERR_ABORTED 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: Same issue with me always Unauthorized. Any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I didn't run this code specifically but this should work like every other get request in jQuery

```
$.get( url, { location: "sunnyvale,ca", format: "json", oauth_consumer_key: oauth_consumer_key, oauth_signature_method: oauth_signature_method, ... } )
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
```

Ref1: jQuery API https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Ref2: Yahoo API: https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/documentation.html

Comment: I will try this out.

Comment: @user979331 The API Doc says,_The API is OAuth protected, need to sign the request with a Yahoo App consumer key and secret_, so send your keys and  the `request parameters` mentioned in docs

Comment: I updated my question with that I tried, I get a 401 error.

Comment: add whatever secret keys instead of the ones I've typed

Comment: I added my client key....there appears to be no where to add private key

Comment: The Doc clearly writes, `On the success page, write down "App ID", "Client ID (Consumer Key)", and "Client Secret (Consumer Secret)" for future use. ` (and then you also have to get yourself whitelisted)

Comment: I think I got it, I have been waiting 3 days to get whitelisted.

Comment: @user979331 can you share the final code with us then?